# C++ passing reference to string itself, won´t compile

Tags: c++, reference

I am using Xcode and it refuses to compile when passing reference to the string object itself.

`(string &text, string remove)`

without `&` it compiles. Is it my code that is wrong or could it be something with the project file?

this is the compiler error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"removeLetters3(std::string, std::string)", referenced from:
  Main() in narcissism.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Code:

```
string removeLetters3(string &text, string remove)
{
for (int i = 0; i < remove.length(); i++)
{
    int pos = 0;

    while ((pos = text.find(remove[i], pos)) != string :: npos)
    {
        text.replace(pos, 1, "");
    }
}
return "";
}
```

and here is how the function is called:

```
string text;
string rletter;
removeLetters3(text, rletter);
```

Comment: ur .h (or any forward decls) i think declares it without the `&` or is this just 1 cpp file?

Comment: That is correct! I´d forgot we use prototypes in C++ , just started using the language. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, your `removeLetters3` implementation returns only the empty string, which seems kind of useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code but judging from your error I would assume that the declaration that the caller sees is this:

```
string removeLetters3(string text, string remove);
```

While your implementation reads

```
string removeLetters3(string &text, string remove) {
```

So when your linker tries to find the implementation of the first one it fails because there is no such implementation.

This is evidenced by the error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"removeLetters3(std::string, std::string)", referenced from:
  Main() in narcissism.o
```

notice the signature. It is **not** saying:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"removeLetters3(std::string&, std::string)", referenced from:
  Main() in narcissism.o
```

Comment: Good catch! It seems to me that there's info missing from the original question & that there's a mismatch between the declaration and the implementation. Of course, if you drop the code as-is into a single file, it builds just fine.